# Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to update multiple rows in a column but when I execute query getting error. Somebody guide me where I am wrong. Thanks in advance

```
  UPDATE TestTaker
  SET TestTaker.Email = 'Replaced'
  WHERE TestTaker.Id IN (SELECT TestTaker.Id FROM TestTaker
  INNER JOIN Questionnaire ON (TestTaker.id = Questionnaire.TestTaker_id)
  WHERE Questionnaire.Project_id IN(SELECT Project.Id FROM Project WHERE NAME LIKE 'abcd'));
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: query getting error? what error you r getting?

Comment: @MarkB 'Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data' here is the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: You are using table 'TestTaker' multiple times in that query, so you have to assign a 'alias' for that table and have to specify this alias for every columns wherever you using.

Comment: @MattRaines Could you please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using table 'TestTaker' multiple times in that query, so you have to assign a 'alias' for that table and have to specify this alias for every columns wherever you using.
Or try to simplify your query like the below one.

```
UPDATE TestTaker
SET TestTaker.Email = 'Replaced'
WHERE TestTaker.Id IN ( SELECT  Questionnaire.TestTaker_id
                        FROM    Questionnaire
                        WHERE   (TestTaker.id = Questionnaire.TestTaker_id)
                            AND Questionnaire.Project_id IN(    SELECT Project.Id 
                                                                FROM Project WHERE NAME LIKE 'abcd')
                        );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. you solved my problem.It worked :)