# MySql Update Trigger with Subquery (#1093 Error)

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

Good evening!

I have a trigger to update a record from my table 'comment' named vote. The trigger will be fired when I update a value named 'vote' in my 'vote' table. For the trigger query, I need to sum up all 'vote' records in table 'vote' and then update in 'comment' the row with the 'comment.id = vote.pid' while 'vote.uid = user.id'.

Trigger Function:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `CommentVoteOnUpdate`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `CommentVoteOnUpdate` AFTER UPDATE ON `vote` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE comment
SET comment.vote = (
    SELECT SUM(vote.vote) 
    FROM vote, comment, user
    WHERE comment.id = pid AND uid = user.id
)
WHERE comment.id = new.pid
```

When I want to update a value in the 'vote' table , then I got the following error message:

"Table 'comment' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data"

Did anyone of you got a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your comment table (In the subquery) an alias. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071167/table-is-specified-twice-both-as-a-target-for-update-and-as-a-separate-source) for more info.